# how to copy sqlite database when installing android application

Tags: android

I am using sqlite database in my application,i want to copy this sqlitedatabase file when creating apk file and paste on mobile during the installation of the application.Is there any packaging options to do this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Ragu, there is a broadcast that occurs when installing apps from the market place but since you are installing your app, the event obviously doesn't get received by your app.
Copy the database file to your assets folder and on the first invocation of the application, you might be able to copy the file from your asset folder into internal storage.

Comment: Also, wouldn't downloading the database from a site be better than including the file in your apk?

Comment: can  you plz give me any link , how to do this iam new to android